# Index HTML in solr using ajax

Tags: jquery, json, solr

i am indexing solr using jquery ajax via json. In the json name/value pair i need to get value from html element in a form. How to send this value in json, as the variable name get indexed in solr instead of value.

```
function signupcall()
{
    var variable=document.getElementById('newemail').value; 

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "http://localhost:8080/solr/User/update?commit=true",
        data : "{ \"add\": { \"doc\": { \"emailaddr\": \"variable\"}} }",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType : "jsonp"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the value of the variable, not the text. See edit below.

```
 function signupcall()
 {
     var variable=document.getElementById('newemail').value; 

     $.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         url : "http://localhost:8080/solr/User/update?commit=true",
         data : "{ \"add\": { \"doc\": { \"emailaddr\": \"" + variable + "\"}} }",
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType : "jsonp"
     });
 }
```